# C: Trying to have variables stored in specific XMM registers

Tags: c, sse

I'm working on a project involving SSE intrinsics and XMM registers, and I would like to use all 16 registers offered. I'm trying to explicitly tell the compiler to do this, but it doesn't seem to be working. For instance, I might write a line like this:

```
register __m128 foo __asm__("xmm12") = _mm_setzero_ps();
```

Where `foo` would be stored at register `xmm12`, and be initialized to zero (I would later be adding to foo, etc)

The thing is, when I look at the assembly code, `xmm12` isn't being used anywhere, even though it actually is necessary for in the code, and I told the compiler to use that register.

I'm having a hard time figuring out what I'm doing wrong. Is my syntax incorrect? Is the compiler ignoring what I'm saying, and if so why?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: sorry not familiar with this topic, but i believe you should tell which compiler you're using - `asm` syntax tends to depend on that quite a lot.

Comment: You are compiling 64 bit code, I presume ? For 32 bit code there are only 8 XMM registers. Either way though, there's probably no good reason to specify particular XMM registers - just use intrinsics and let the compiler do the register allocation for you.

Comment: gcc? if yes then how you call it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the real problem wasn't with the 'register' keyword. The compiler was right to ignore that; it was a silly idea. Ultimately what I had to do was unroll my 'for' loop a few more times than I already had. In the end this made my code faster and just happened to use more registers. I made the mistake of thinking "using more registers would lead to faster code", when register usage is more a side effect than anything else.

Thank you for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

I just tried an experiment with gcc 4.2 and it looks like you can only specify the XMM registers successfully with -O0. As soon as you turn on optimisation then gcc will change the register allocation. So it looks like you can either have complete control and do all the optimisation manually, if you really want to, so long as you use `gcc -O0`, otherwise let gcc take care of optimisation and register allocation for you.